# Get control after user authentication for sending modified user details

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

The general intent is controlling user details visibility while interacting with third party services.

Our application is using a single sign-on (SSO). Hence third party services should use Keycloak for user authentication. But we would like to provide information about user from our application, not from Keycloak.

For example, Stephen Clark has work email `stephen.clark@jourrapide.com` and personal email `stephen.c@armyspy.com`. He is authenticating using Keycloak. After authentication third party service would like to request additional information about Stephen. We would like to send information to third party service based on specific user settings. For instance, if Stephen is using his work profile then our application should send `stephen.clark@jourrapide.com` as an email to third party service. But the `stephen.c@armyspy.com` email should be sent for Stephen's personal profile. The same should be done for other user details.

That's why our application should get control after user authentication and send appropriate user details to third party service.

I assume that following options could help us to achieve this goal. But I do not have enough information for implementation. It would be good if you could provide me with some options with implementation examples.

1. Use the "Post Login Flow" in Keycloak.
2. Create custom identity provider in Keycloak.
3. Use the Impersonate user functionality in Keycloak with REST API for switching to required user.

Comment: These are a fictional email addresses hopefully?

Comment: @Greenonline These emails were auto generated for this example.